# How to capture an all event from a iframe to other iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I want to capture all event from an iframe and what ever event happen to an ifram i want to execute the same event to the other iframe how can i achieve this , please show me the way .

Here is my iframes.

```
<table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
  <tr>
    <th><iframe width="100%" height="100%"src="http://google.com"></iframe></th>
    <th><iframe width="100%" height="100%"src="http://google.com"></iframe></th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: if you are loading the external content in iframes i think it is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this because the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will deny you all access to external iframes.